# Error: Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded In Shopify CLI Theme Development

Tags: shopify, shopify-storefront-api, shopify-cli

I'm encountering an issue in my Shopify CLI theme development where I'm getting the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded." The stack trace points to file system operations, specifically within the stubborn-fs module.

Here's the relevant portion of the stack trace:

i tried uninstalling the shopify CLI and installing it back, but still thesame thing